# different query for the same result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know exactly the differences for this query :

1st:

```
SELECT * FROM cc_inscription 
LEFT JOIN cc_paiement 
ON cc_paiement.inscription_id = cc_inscription.inscription_id 
WHERE cc_inscription.course_id=1 
ORDER BY cc_inscription.inscription_id ASC; 
(4107 records, 19s execution)
```

2nd:

```
SELECT * FROM cc_inscription, cc_paiement 
WHERE cc_paiement.inscription_id = cc_inscription.inscription_id 
AND cc_inscription.course_id=1 
ORDER BY cc_inscription.inscription_id ASC; 
(3780 records, 0.400s)
```

I don't understand why the first take 4107 records and the 2nd 3780 ...

And how I can optimise the first query ? 19s it's very bad !

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query with `LEFT JOIN` gives you all records from `cc_inscription` even if there is no related record in the table `cc_paiement`. If there is no matching record the `cc_paiement` columns will return `NULL` for that row.

The second query will only give you records from table `cc_inscription` if there is a related record in `cc_paiement`.

You can make the first query the same as the second by removing the word `LEFT`.

You can optimise your query by creating the right indexes.

Comment: I have fleshed out your answer and tweaked some grammar.. didn't feel right to add a new answer.